# Filling NULL with values of the same date. MSQL 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help. Let's say I noticed some errors in my temperature sensor readings (table temp_sens). Can anyone suggest me on how to fill in the NULL value with
(1) Value of the same date and time
(2) Average value between the preceding and following value of the NULL.

```
      DateAndTime         Temp         
2017-02-28 12:10:03.000 | NULL
2017-02-28 12:10:03.000 | 30.0
2017-02-28 12:05:01.000 | NULL
2017-02-28 12:05:01.000 | 30.7
2017-02-28 12:00:01.000 | NULL
2017-02-28 12:00:01.000 | 30.2
```

So the columns will look something like this

For (1)

```
    DateAndTime         Temp         
2017-02-28 12:10:03.000 | 30.0
2017-02-28 12:10:03.000 | 30.0
2017-02-28 12:05:01.000 | 30.7
2017-02-28 12:05:01.000 | 30.7
2017-02-28 12:00:01.000 | 30.2
2017-02-28 12:00:01.000 | 30.2
```

For (2)

```
      DateAndTime         Temp         
2017-02-28 12:10:03.000 | 15.0
2017-02-28 12:10:03.000 | 30.0
2017-02-28 12:05:01.000 | 30.35
2017-02-28 12:05:01.000 | 30.7
2017-02-28 12:00:01.000 | 30.45
2017-02-28 12:00:01.000 | 30.2
```

Comment: This gets tricky because of the possibility of having a series of `NULL` values for X number of records.  In this case, we can't simply update using any of your logic.  In such a general case, I think your problem has to be viewed as a gaps and islands situation.

Comment: "Preceding" and "following" don't make sense unless you define an order, and if you have multiple identical `DateAndTime` values, an order defined solely on that is insufficient. Do you have some other columns in your table that would allow you to define a sensible order?

Comment: No answer to 1 as there could be more than on value matching the date.   There is no answer to 2 and a table has not inherent order.

Comment: @Paparazzi For no. 1, I have verified that there is not more than one value that matches for a given date and time. Appreciate your answer for no 2.

Comment: @hvd - Thank you.Unfortunately the rest of the columns refer to other readings from the sensor. The only sensible reference for the column is the date and time stamp. I wanted to program the whole thing such that if it detects a NULL value, it needs to wait for a new value to poped out and grab that value as well as the value before the NULL value is seen, then average both values and replace the NULL with it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I see. That makes sense. Then I guess I just have to use ISNULL and replace the NULL value with a sensible value or I could just search every NULL value and replace it with the value of the same date and time. Thanks guys for helping me out

Comment: @Dein If you're able to add an identity column to the table, that would let you figure out which of the rows with identical timestamps was inserted first, and from there you could make an attempt at an average. If you opt for the other approach (which effectively amounts to excluding the rows that don't have values) you don't need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the same date and time, just use window functions:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(t.temp,
                max(t.temp) over (partition by dateandtime)
               ) as temp
from t;
```

For an "average", you need a stable ordering -- one where the keys are unique.  If you have such an ordering (and your sample data does not), then something like this would work:

```
select . . .,
       coalesce(t.temp,
                (coalesce(lag(t.temp) over (order by dateandtime), 0) +
                 coalesce(lead(t.temp) over (order by dateandtime), 0)
                ) / 2
               )
from t;
```

Treating `NULL` values as 0 seems quite awkward, but that is what your sample results do.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to actually write a solution to my inquiry. I have tried your solution but it didn't work. I was thinking of using case statement where if the 'Temp' column sees NULL value, then it will look at the matching date and grab the temp value and replace the NULL